# Регулярнные выраженния

Tags: java

```
p: a\\b
m : a [b
"a\\\\b"
```

p это паттерн, m совпадения.

Почему так получилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в строке `"a\\b"` экранирование получается для слеша, строка становится с одним слешом `a\b`. В регулярном выражении `\b` воспринимается как граница слова.